# Does the disappearing floating menu bar in use by Facebook and others have a name?

Tags: terminology, names

What I'm talking about is the **`Status / Photo / Check In`** bar in this image:

[image]

It's visible when you're at the top of the scroll view, or after you scroll up and let go. It slides away when you scroll down.

Does it have a coined name? Else, what is the most easily understood thing to call it?

Comment: Within my team, we call that section the "top slide space" or "scroll nav". Though I'm not sure of the official name.

Comment: I thought the sticky headers were new. When did things sliding with the page became hip again? :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern is called **Quick Return** and was (to my knowledge) developed by [Roman Nurik](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+RomanNurik/posts/1Sb549FvpJt).

It was initially introduced in Google Now application for Android, and has spread to other applications after that with some differing behaviour.

There is a blog post about it that you can read [here](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/search?q=quick%20return).

Comment: That blog post describes the pattern of behaviour as Quick Return - but it doesn't settle on a single name for the screen element which has this behaviour. It variously calls it "_quick return container_", "_quick return part_" and "_quick return bar_".

Comment: @vincebowdren well.. I'm quite sure what the OP is interested to know IS what the pattern for this behaviour is called, and not what this particular Facebook action bar is called. And the pattern is called Quick Return.

Comment: Quick return has a nice ring to it!

Comment: @rk. yea, it does doesn't it! I get some Quick-E-Mart associations to it. =)

Answer (score 2):

I would go with a '**Slide down header**'. The sliding in headers, which slide down after you scroll past a point are referred to as 'Scroll initiated slide down header' by [this post](http://return-true.com/2010/04/scroll-activated-slide-down-header-with-jquery/) (which has been reposted quite a few times).

The new thing in mobile, like you mentioned with the facebook app is, the **trigger is reversed**. Instead of scrolling down, you scroll up past a certain point to active the slide down header.